# How to correctly add the date to the date?

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++, and i have a problem with Unixtime adding. For example, I have a date `8.10.2014 14:49`

I need to add 26 days, 12 hours, 44 minutes to it. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

struct Date {
    int Minute;
    int Hour;
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
};

int main(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    Date startDate;
    std::cin >> startDate.Year;
    std::cin >> startDate.Month;
    std::cin >> startDate.Day;
    std::cin >> startDate.Hour;
    std::cin >> startDate.Minute;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo->tm_year = startDate.Year - 1900;
    timeinfo->tm_mon = startDate.Month -1;
    timeinfo->tm_mday = startDate.Day;
    timeinfo->tm_hour = startDate.Hour;
    timeinfo->tm_min = startDate.Minute;

    rawtime = mktime ( timeinfo ) + 2555027;

    std::cout << rawtime << std::endl;

    struct tm *tm = localtime(&rawtime);
    char date[80];
    strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%Y %m %d %H %M", tm);
    std::cout << date;
}
```

The answers is approximately similar to the truth, but don't correct. Why?

Comment: The simplest method is to convert the date into seconds.  Next convert your duration into seconds.  Add the quantities.  Convert the sum into a date.  Otherwise you will have to deal with *carries* such as from 24 hours to a day and 365.25 days into a year.  Instead of seconds you could use minutes; the least precise quantity.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about 365.25 days into a year. Maybe you know, what is the easiest way to convert the date to seconds? I mean, without dealing with leap years? And to turn seconds into the year, using built-in methods?

Comment: There should be some date / time functions that return seconds or milliseconds from a `struct tm`.  Search the internet.

Comment: @thomas-matthews, thank you!

Comment: 2555027 != 26 days, 12 hours, 44 minutes. You want 2292240.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11 (or C++14) and a relatively up-to-date compiler, you can use this library:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

like so:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "tz.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto zone = current_zone();
    auto time = make_zoned(current_zone(), local_days{8_d/10/2014} + 14h + 49min);
    time = time.get_sys_time() + days{26} + 12h + 44min;
    std::cout << time << '\n';
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to what you have, which assumes that the date you specified is in your computer's local timezone, and that you also want the results in your computer's local timezone.  For me this outputs:

2014-11-04 02:33:00 EST

However you also mentioned "Unixtime", which to me means [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  This time is measured in UTC, which lacks complications such as daylight saving time.  If it is the intent to do this in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), you can do this more easily and cheaply with this library:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto time = sys_days{8_d/10/2014} + 14h + 49min + days{26} + 12h + 44min;
    std::cout << time << '\n';
}
```

which will portably output:

2014-11-04 03:33

The use of the "chrono literals" (e.g. `14h`) implies C++14.  If you are in C++11, you can substitute in the more verbose `hours{14}` (`hours` is in namespace `std::chrono`).  If you are in C++03, well, then, [never mind](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE6EP3Z0PSU). :-)